# Original source server of a SQL Server backup file

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I've searched for an answer for this here and google but had no luck, hopefuly someone here knows.

At work we have multiple development and testing database servers (SQL Server 2008, 2014) I have a backup file someone gave me to restore locally for some tests, but I need to find out which server it came from (apparently nobody knows for sure).

Is there a way to find out what server the backup file was taken from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get the info you want by using RESTORE HEADERONLY

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
GO
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/105/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-sql-server-backup-file/

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!!